# DateTime.Now = Cannot provide the value: host value not found

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, iis-express

The system I'm working on modifying uses forms authentication and creates a ticket to authenticate the user.  I get the `Cannot provide the value: host value not found` error when attempting to retrieve the system time, IE; `Dim mytime as DateTime = DateTime.Now`.  I'm using VB.Net with VS 2019 on windows 10 and SQL Server as the state server.  What am a missing?  I'm not real familiar with Windows 10, I assume it's a setting with IIS Express or Windows 10, I just don't know what/where.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on that line? Seems like a completely different problem.

Comment: The full error page is needed. Edit your question to include that.

Comment: The page doesn't crash.  I assume that is because the cookie doesn't need the expiration date/time.  After the statement is executed, I get `mytime = the value: host value not found`.

Comment: Debugger problem, avoid previews if you need to get your job done.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/786837/debug-in-visual-basic.html

Comment: @Hans Passant, ah, ok .... I'll wait to see what they come back with.  Interesting .... Thanks.

Comment: A similar workaround to [Andre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285971/1204599) would be to type `?mytime.ToString` into the Immediate Window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [developer community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/786837/debug-in-visual-basic.html), solution is to add

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString}", Target:=GetType(Date))>
```

to your `AssemblyInfo.vb` (located in the `MyProject` folder of your Startup project)

Not the fix I wanted to see - but it works.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. This only started happening since I updated my VS install yesterday. Hopefully a temporary thing, adding lines to the assembly is a bad work around.

Comment: This breaks C# though.  I call VB from a C# unit test, and now i'm getting this:  error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Answer (score 2):

In the Immediate Window, display the value "toString"ed, i.e. ?variablename.ToString will display it correctly.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In January 2020, a patch has been released from Visual Studio fixing this problem. Upgrade your VS Community and it should be working just fine! ([Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/786837/debug-in-visual-basic.html))